# Is there a way to use log4net.dll to read a log

Tags: logging, log4net

I have a short question: is there a way to use the log4net-dll for reading logfiles in C#?
We need a internal reader for our logs with personalisized filters and combination of several logfiles.

I have tried it with regular expressions and string.split, but it seems very low-performant.

Comment: Log4net is for *writing* logs. If regex and splits are too slow, don't log to plain text, use proper DB with indexing.

Comment: log4net is not for reading logs. you can save log entries in CSV format in the first place. then parse CSV files is easier.